# Why do python generators and functions share the "def" keyword?

Tags: design, programming-languages, python

Consider the following:

```
def some_function():
    return 1

def some_generator():
    yield 1
```

In the code above, `some_function` is a function, while `some_generator` is a generator. They look quite similar.

The problem that I have when reading code is that I need to scan through every line in a "function" looking for the `yield` keyword before I can determine whether it is actually a function or a generator!

It just seems to me that using a different keyword for generators would make more sense, e.g.:

```
gen some_generator():
    yield 1
```

What are the merits of using the `def` keyword for both generators and functions? Why has a new keyword is not been introduced to separate functions and generators?

Comment: I don't know the real answer, but I often start out writing functions that return lists, then convert to generators when it seems right.  Having the syntax match makes this more natural.

Comment: @StevenBurnap Derek's suggestion of using something like `gen` instead of `def` wouldn't make that transformation significantly more onerous.

Comment: In general, language designers usually try to avoid adding unnecessary keywords.  Every keyword they add is an identifier that programs aren't allowed to use for other purposes.

Comment: @jamesdlin: But the question is arguing that a new keyword would be **necessary**.

Comment: @Giorgio Huh?  Clearly a new keyword was *not* necessary since Python does use the same keyword for both functions and generators.

Comment: @jamesdlin: Of course you can distinguish functions and generators by looking at their body, but the question argues that using different keywords would make the code more readable.

Comment: @Giorgio I never disputed that a new keyword would make the code more readable.  My original point is simply that language designers try to avoid adding keywords so that they avoid breaking existing programs.  You claimed that a new keyword would be necessary.  It is not.  It would simply be nice to have.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"What are the merits of using the def keyword for both generators and functions?"

While they are mechanically different, in practice when I use them they are often effectively the same to me conceptually (I don't think much of calling `range()` vs `xrange()`).

In terms of understanding what the function is all about quickly though, I agree something is lost with the use of `def`, but things should not be too obfuscated within the function to begin with.

Even an implicit `return None` can confuse the intended behavior of a function after a long bit of conditionals (as in, was a `return None` intended as a final behavior or an oversight in the logic). But those are just my believies about it.

I don't feel my argument is particularly convincing though so I will just defer to [PEP 255](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/):

> Issue:  Introduce another new keyword (say, "gen" or "generator") in
>      place of "def", or otherwise alter the syntax, to distinguish
>      generator-functions from non-generator functions.
>
> Con:  In practice (how you think about them), generators *are*
>      functions, but with the twist that they're resumable.  The mechanics of
>      how they're set up is a comparatively minor technical issue, and
>      introducing a new keyword would unhelpfully overemphasize the
>      mechanics of how generators get started (a vital but tiny part of a
>      generator's life).
>
> Pro:  In reality (how you think about them), generator-functions are
>      actually factory functions that produce generator-iterators as if by
>      magic.  In this respect they're radically different from non-generator
>      functions, acting more like a constructor than a function, so reusing
>      "def" is at best confusing.  A "yield" statement buried in the body is
>      not enough warning that the semantics are so different.
>
> BDFL:  "def" it stays.  No argument on either side is totally
>      convincing, so I have consulted my language designer's intuition.  It
>      tells me that the syntax proposed in the PEP is exactly right - not too
>      hot, not too cold.  But, like the Oracle at Delphi in Greek mythology,
>      it doesn't tell me why, so I don't have a rebuttal for the arguments
>      against the PEP syntax.  The best I can come up with (apart from
>      agreeing with the rebuttals ... already made) is "FUD".  If this had
>      been part of the language from day one, I very much doubt it would have
>      made Andrew Kuchling's "Python Warts" page.

Comment: It is worth noting that the new `await` (and  `async with` and `async for`) syntax constructs added in [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/), which work very similar to `yield from`, require the function they're used in to be declared using `async def` instead of a just `def`.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Adding new keywords risks breaking existing programs.**  Language designers generally try to avoid adding new keywords, especially for language features added after the language has already gained some popularity.  Every keyword they add is an identifier that programs aren't allowed to use for other purposes, so adding a keyword could potentially break existing programs.  Language designers have to weigh the benefits of a new keyword against the costs.
2. **I doubt that *defining* a separate keyword for generators would have much benefit.** To understand whether a symbol corresponds to the name of a function or to the name of a generator is something that matters to callers, and callers shouldn't have to (and sometimes can't) look at what keyword was used to implement it.  That's the responsibility of better naming conventions and documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Generators are functions that evaluate lazily. Given that they are the same thing at base, it makes sense that they would use the same keyword. One option might be to use a comment to identify which is which for a given instance:

```
def some_function(): #This is a function.
    return 1

def some_generator(): #This is a generator.
    yield 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it is because it is more Pythonic but what do I know? ;)

I don't really think that it matters all that much. It is easier to remember for me because no need to memorize them both.

EDIT: The PEP might say, you could investigate there.

Comment: Thanks! In fact, the PEP does say! See [PEP-255](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) for the pros/cons and final decision regarding a new keyword for generators.

Comment: With Pythonic meaning: "The way it is done in Python"?